# Zilberman seforim

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, jewish-books

Does anybody know of seforim written by members of the Zilberman community in Yerushalayim? I'm looking primarily for halachic works about implementing the Vilna Gaon's shitahs today, but I'd be interested in anything they've produced.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the Zilberman community insist on the wearing of Murex-dyed techeiles?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Nice. Sorry for the off-topic comment there.